# Dynamic Creation of View/Models (MVC or Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I'm going to be starting a new project creating a Web Application in either an MVC or Razor framework

It's going to rely quite heavily on dynamic creation of components/elements for maximum user customization and I've looked around and can't seem to find a solid answer that says it's doable.

Essentially the kind of functionality I'm looking for will work similarly to Jira, where you can create entirely new projects, dashboards etc and all can be viewed from a homepage... Everything I've seen bases the answer on looping through a list of pre-created views... No creation at run time

Any answers greatly appreciated, happy to go into more details if unclear.

Comment: These views are not really dynamic in the sense you are thinking of.  They are generally Dictionary<string, string>.  If you want a 'new' field, just add it to the dictionary.

Comment: Both Razor and MVC use models. A model is an object you pass from the controller to the view that has information about what should be displayed. Using C# code in the view in combination with this model, you can make pages as dynamic as you want. The idea is you create a basic layout with the HTML then fill in the rest with information from the model.